# convergence of GMERS (diagonalizable Matrices)

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-linear-algebra

there are various books and articles, which states that the GMRES-Algorithmn convergence in maximal n steps for a diagonalizable $n \times n   $ Matrix X.

Usually it's sufficent to show

$$  \|r_k\| \le cond(X)\|r_0\| (\min_{p \in \Pi_k} \max_{i} |p(\lambda_i)|)$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the Eigenvalues of X, and $\Pi_k$ is the space of polynomials with degree $\le k$.

My question: How does it follow that for a diagonalizable $n \times n$ Matrix with $k \le n$ distinct eigenvalues the GMRES breaks in maximal k steps? It's just statet a "trivial" in the books.

Greetings.

Comment: First, $\Pi_k$ is not really a space of polynomials but rather a set of polynomials $p$ of degree $\leq k$ such that $p(0)=1$. Second, take $p$ to be the minimal polynomial of $A$ normalized such that $p(0)=1$. (In addition, you need to assume that $A$ is nonsingular.)

Comment: I still dont get it. If I want convergence in k steps $\|r_k\| = 0$ so this min max term has do be 0, but why is this the case with p minimal polynomial?

Comment: What values does a minimal polynomial attain in the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Comment: zero. of course, thank you!